# Django: set dynamic array in urlpatterns from urls.py

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, url

I have this function that I want to use in order to delete some records from a database. It takes as input an array of ints.

```
function deleteScript(idList){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/delete',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            ids: idList
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert('success')
        }
    })
    console.log('ajax sent')
}
```

How can I set the django dynamic url so that no matter the list, the request would always call the same method (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/delete/?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2` `http://localhost:8000/delete/?ids%5B%5D=5` would go to `delete/`)?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_data),
    path('delete/<list:ids>', views.delete)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the id list as comma separated values:

```
?id=1,4,5
```

And then parse it in Python to a list.

```py
id_param = request.GET['id']
try:
  ids = [int(a) for a in id_param.split(',')]
except ValueError:
  # handle improper request
```